# Tomcat + OSGi + Hibernate + maven ClassNotFoundException org.hibernate.ServiceRegistry

Tags: hibernate, maven, tomcat, classnotfoundexception, equinox

I've embedded OSGi framework in an Apache Tomcat server (7.0.52) using the Bridge.WAR. I can use it and run bundles on it.
My bundles are built using maven.

Now I would like to access to a database and get data using one bundle. I've mapped my classes by JPA annotations and I would like to use Hql queries to get data. For the data access I would like to use hibernate, I have it in the dependencies in the POM file.
After I've built **mvn clean install** and embedded in the OSGi container I try to start it but it misses the classes of the **org.hibernate** package.

I don't know what to do with it. Can anybody help? I'm totally lost...

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.database</groupId>
    <artifactId>RecipePrDatabase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.database.service.impl.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.0alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
               </dependency>
           <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
               </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and I use this for connect:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                conf.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(sr);
    }

    public void initDB() throws Exception {

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public void closeDB() {
        if (session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What way do you use for embedding your jar? Is there any log information about missed org.hibernate? I suppose that your OSGI container has no clue about hibernate package.
Your `<Import-Package>` section contains only org.osgi.framework, however you also need to specify org.hibernate if it's used by your bundle (see more details about `<Import-Package>`: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

Comment: Yes You are right, the <Import-Package> is needed! Now my problem is that i can not integrate the hibernate to my framework. Do you know maybe a way for that?
I use an equinox container(Bridge.war) to integrate the technology in Tomcat.
I think hibernate have a lot of dependencies and i cannot install all of them manually.

Comment: If the problem is in dependencies only, so maybe embedding dependencies might solve it. Check this post as a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438167/trying-to-build-an-osgi-bundle-in-maven-with-embedded-dependencies-cant-seem-t